# Create an array of objects from a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, nested

I've a nested object 'empData'.
I need to iterate over each of the keys in my object and return an array of objects.
Each key inside my object 'empData' is again an object.

Now, I need to return an array of object as:

Expected output:

```
[{
 "team": "AUS",
 "name": "John"
}, {
 "team": "CAN",
 "name": "Steve"
}, {
 "team": "IND",
 "name": "Robbie"
}, {
 "team": "IRE",
 "name": "James"
}, {
 "team": "USA",
 "name": "Austin"
}];
```

My Code:

```js
function getData() {
 const empData = {
  "AUS": {
   "isRetired": true,
   "name": "John"
  },
  "CAN": {
   "name": "Steve"
  },
  "IND": {
   "name": "Robbie"
  },
  "IRE": {
   "name": "James"
  },
  "USA": {
   "name": "Austin"
  }
 };
 Object.keys(empData).map(function(eachKey) {
  const obj = {
   team: eachKey,
   name: eachKey.name
  };
  console.log(obj);
  return obj;
 });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getData()">Get Data</button>
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` the `Object.entries` instead, so you can extract both the key (to get the `team` and the value (so you can get the `name`) at once:

```js
const empData = {
  "AUS": {
    "isRetired": true,
    "name": "John"
  },
  "CAN": {
    "name": "Steve"
  },
  "IND": {
    "name": "Robbie"
  },
  "IRE": {
    "name": "James"
  },
  "USA": {
    "name": "Austin"
  }
};
const getData = () => {
  const result = Object.entries(empData).map(([team, { name }]) => ({
    team,
    name
  }));
  console.log(result);
};
```

```html
<button onclick="getData()">Get Data</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

change    `name: eachKey.name`

```
 name: empData[eachKey].name



function getData() {
 const empData = {
  "AUS": {
   "isRetired": true,
   "name": "John"
  },
  "CAN": {
   "name": "Steve"
  },
  "IND": {
   "name": "Robbie"
  },
  "IRE": {
   "name": "James"
  },
  "USA": {
   "name": "Austin"
  }
 };
 Object.keys(empData).map(function(eachKey) {
  const obj = {
   team: eachKey,
   name: empData[eachKey].name
  };
  console.log(obj);
  return obj;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array. Use `map` to loop thru the array.

`Object.entries` first element is the key and the second is the value.

```js
const empData = {
  "AUS": {
    "isRetired": true,
    "name": "John"
  },
  "CAN": {
    "name": "Steve"
  },
  "IND": {
    "name": "Robbie"
  },
  "IRE": {
    "name": "James"
  },
  "USA": {
    "name": "Austin"
  }
};

var result = Object.entries(empData).map(([team, {name}]) => ({team,name}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for..in` to iterate iver the object and create a new object with relevant keys and values and push to another array

```js
function getData() {
  const empData = {
    "AUS": {
      "isRetired": true,
      "name": "John"
    },
    "CAN": {
      "name": "Steve"
    },
    "IND": {
      "name": "Robbie"
    },
    "IRE": {
      "name": "James"
    },
    "USA": {
      "name": "Austin"
    }
  };

  let newData = [];
  for (let keys in empData) {
    newData.push({
      team: keys,
      name: empData[keys].name
    })
  }
  console.log(newData)
}

getData()
```